# React native FlatList not showing images

Tags: react-native

I want to show list of images on my app horizontally. I know if I give prop to my flat list `horizontal ={true}` it will be horizontal but the problem is that `FlatList` not showing images at all. This is what I have tried so far

```
const data = [
    {
      imageUrl: "https://c7.uihere.com/files/45/824/935/united-states-win-the-white-house-hotel-business-company-refresh-icon-thumb.jpg",
      id:"1"
    },
    {
      imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/160x160",
      id:"2"
    },
    {
      imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/160x160",
      id:"3"
    },
    {
      imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/160x160",
      id:"4"
    },
    {
      imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/160x160",
      id:"5"
    },
    {
      imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/160x160",
      id:"6"
    }
  ];

export default class CircularImage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super (props)
        this.state = {
            data:data
        }
    }


  render() {
  return (
    <FlatList 
    data = {this.state.data}
    renderItem = {({item}) => {
      <Image  styel = {styles.circularImage} source = {{uri : item.imageUrl}}/>
    }}
    keyExtractor ={item => {item.id.toString()}}
    />
  )
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo. `styel`  should be `style`.

Comment: Ohh....But return statement made my day. **Thnks BTW for pointing that out**.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `return` statement in your `renderItem` function

```
<FlatList 
    data = {this.state.data}
    renderItem = {({item}) => {
      return <Image  styel = {styles.circularImage} source = {{uri : item.imageUrl}}/>
    }}
    keyExtractor ={item => {item.id.toString()}}
    />
```

OR

```
<FlatList 
    data = {this.state.data}
    renderItem = {({item}) => <Image  styel = {styles.circularImage} source = {{uri : item.imageUrl}}/>
    }
    keyExtractor ={item => {item.id.toString()}}
    />
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The return statement did it

Answer (score 3):

In React Native, image has to have **width and height** in order to show. You might missed out of that part.